# ¿Por qué no actualiza la fila correspondiente en PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy realizando una aplicación en PHP. Voy progresando, pero ahora me sucede que no actualiza la fila correspondiente con el valor.

Mi código es el siguiente:

Para obtener el id para conocer la fila a actualizar:

```
<td>";

             
                    echo "<form method='post'>
                        <button name='btnUpdate'  class='page title-action'>Actualizar</button>                
        <input type='hidden'  name='id' class='page-litle-action'  value=$id>
        </form>
         </td></tr>";
```

Para realizar la petición post:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['btnUpdate'])) {
        $id_ = $_POST['id'];

        create_menu_to_update($id_);
    }
}

function update_name($id)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $tabla_actualizar = "{$wpdb->prefix}our_users";
    $new_name = $_POST['new_name'];
    $wpdb->update(
        $tabla_actualizar,

        array(
            'name' => $new_name,

        ),

        array('Id' => $id)
    );
}

function create_menu_to_update($id)
{
    echo "
        <form method='post'>
            <div>
                <button name='btnNew' id='btnNew' class='page title-action'>Actualizar</button>

            </div>
            <br><br>
            <hr>

            <label for='new_name'><strong>Nuevo nombre</strong></label>
            <br>
            
            <input type='text' name='new_name' id='new_name' style='width:100%'>
            
            <br>
            <hr>
        </form>";

    if (isset($_POST['btnNew'])) {
        update_name($id);
    }
}
```

El formulario se  crea (es de solo un input), pero al pulsar el botón, no hace nada. No cambia los valores. Perdón por la pesadez, pero es que estoy atascado en algo que en teoría no es muy complicado, y no logro dar con la solución. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: No actualiza porque el formulario no incluye el nuevo valor y, por cierto, no muestras el código de la función `create_menu_to_update()`

Comment: Corregido. Gracias por la aclaración

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el formulario no estás incluyendo ID, puedes hacerlo con un campo oculto:

```
function create_menu_to_update($id)
{
    echo "
        <form method='post'>
            <div>
                <button name='btnNew' id='btnNew' class='page title-action'>Actualizar</button>

            </div>
            <br><br>
            <hr>

            <label for='new_name'><strong>Nuevo nombre</strong></label>
            <br>
            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>
            <input type='text' name='new_name' id='new_name' style='width:100%'>
            
            <br>
            <hr>
        </form>";
    // No creo que esta parte se ejecute aquí    
    if (isset($_POST['btnNew'])) {
        update_name($id);
    }
}
```

Al inicio de tu script analiza el si el botón `btnNew` fue el que se recibió:

```
if (isset($_POST['btnUpdate'])) {
    $id_ = $_POST['id'];
    create_menu_to_update($id_);
} elseif($isset($_POST['btnNew'])) {
    update_name($_POST['id']);
}
```

Con esto debería funcionar, pero te faltan validaciones, por ejemplo:

- ID correcto, si es numérico, que sea mayor que cero
- El nombre no debe estar vacío y, tal vez, tenga una longitud mínima
- En general, revisar que realmente se reciben los campos esperados del formulario o, de lo contrario, asignar un valor por defecto

Comment: Funciona. Gracias por aportar tu ingenio y ayuda. Feliz 2022